# BMW manual transmission slow to accelerate but only in certain gears

Tags: engine, manual-transmission, bmw, acceleration

After a service where the engine computer was replaced, I've noticed that certain gears are not behaving normally. 2nd, 4th and 6th behave normally: if I have my foot down on the gas pedal, it continues to accelerate and rev up smoothly. But in 3rd and 5th (I would say 1st feels weird too), pressing down on the pedal gives an initial burst of acceleration but then cuts off. It continues to rev up really slowly and accelerates really slowly. If I "pump the gas" by taking my foot off completely and flooring it again, and repeating, it accelerates and revs up by chaining together those bursts and that is how 2nd, 4th and 6th feel = continuous acceleration. It also feels weird if I'm in 1st, 3rd or 5th and take my foot off. It jerks a bit as if disengaging something. It doesn't do that in the other gears.

The car is a 2015 BMW 228i manual transmission, less than 40k miles. No service lights are on now, but before the service at the dealership there was a check engine light that is gone now. It drove perfectly before the service.

I'm at a loss for how to address this or the terminology/jargon for this issue. Calling my service advisor, they said the computer reset meant the car had to relearn my driving habits. It's been 400 miles since then and also it's a manual transmission so I'm not sure what it's learning...

Any help is appreciated.